# A doubt regarding the proof of Cauchy's theorem in group theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $N$ a subgroup. On pg.61 of Herstein's "Topics in Algebra", it says

> Let $b^{o(N)}=e$. Then $(Nb)^{o(N)}=N$

I don't understand why that is. $Nb=\{n_1 b,n_2 b, n_3 b,\dots\}$, where $n_1,n_2,n_3,\dots \in N$. For some $n_i\in N$, $(n_i b)^{o(N)}=(n_i)^{o(N)}b^{o(N)}\text{ (as $G$ is abelian)}=e.e=e$

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What "Hershtein's Algebra"? There is "Abstract Algebra" and "Topics in Algebra". Please be precise...

Comment: $(Nb)^{o(N)}$ is referring to the multiplication in $G/N$. The fact you mention is merely because the quotient map is a homomorphism. Please see what $Nb\times Nb$ means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $Nb\cdot Nb$ is not the set of elements $n_1b\cdot n_1b$, $n_1\in N$, but rather the set of elements $n_1b\cdot n_2b$, $n_1,n_2\in N$.

Because $n_1, n_2$ can be any elements of $N$, and don't have to be the same, we get $Nb\cdot Nb =Nb^2$.

Martin Brandenburg's answer gives the perspective you need to develop.

Answer (score 3):

Down with cosets, they only cause confusions! $G/N$ is a group equipped with a homomorphism $\pi : G \to G/N$. It is surjective with kernel $N$. Remember that, and you will never need anything else to know about quotient groups.

Now, the statement is just that $b^n = e$  (where $n=o(N)$, whatever this is) implies that $\pi(b)^n = e$. But this is simply because $\pi$ is a homomorphism.